# Python 2 and 3 differences in hashing a uuid

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, uuid

I have some py2 code that works in python 2:

```
    import uuid
    import hashlib

    playername = "OfflinePlayer:%s" % name  # name is just a text only username
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(playername)
    d = bytearray(m.digest())
    d[6] &= 0x0f
    d[6] |= 0x30
    d[8] &= 0x3f
    d[8] |= 0x80
    print(uuid.UUID(bytes=str(d)))
```

However, when the code when run in python3, it produces "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" when m.update() is attempted.  I tried to endcode it first with the default utf-8 by:

```
m.update(playername.encode())
```

but now this line -

```
print(uuid.UUID(bytes=str(d)))
```

produces this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/uuid.py", line 149, in __init__
    raise ValueError('bytes is not a 16-char string')
ValueError: bytes is not a 16-char string
```

I then tried to decode it back, but the bitwise operations have evidently ruined it (I am guessing?):

```
    print(uuid.UUID(bytes=(d.decode())))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I don't honestly know what the purpose of the bitwise operations is in the "big-picture".  The code snippet in general is supposed to produce the same expected UUID every time based on the spelling of the username.

I just want this code to do the same job in Python3 that it did in Python 2 :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
m.update(playername.encode('utf-8'))
```

Should properly encode your string.

```
print(uuid.UUID(bytes=bytes(d)))
```

Should return the UUID properly.

**Example:**

https://repl.it/EyuG/0

Comment: Thanks!  The encode worked without specifying the utf-8, but using bytes = bytes(d) is what worked the majic.  Thanks for a quick solution!

Comment: @SurestTexas: If any of the names have special characters in them I would recommend using `encode('utf-8')`, otherwise you could have unpredictable results — cheers!

Comment: I'll do that to be safe and since explicit is better than implicit.  Thanks!